# do.call in R - Kaggle starter script

Tags: r, kaggle

When, I was going through the starter R script for one one the Kaggle competitions, I saw this function being created to find the sum of all rows. Here is the code:

```
#Function to sum across rows for variables defined
psum <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE) {
     rowSums(do.call(cbind, list(...)), na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

Can someone please explain what is going on in this function?

Also, how is this different from using just `rowSums`?

Comment: Did you look at the `?do.call` help page? Did you see what types of objects where being passed to the `psum` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `do.call` is not needed. It could have (and should have) been written in a simpler fashion like this:

```
psum2 <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE) rowSums(cbind(...), na.rm = na.rm)

psum2(BOD, BOD)
# [1] 18.6 24.6 44.0 40.0 41.2 53.6

psum(BOD, BOD) # same
# [1] 18.6 24.6 44.0 40.0 41.2 53.6
```

**Note:** In general we use do.call when we don't know how many arguments are going to be passed to a function so we want to pass the function a list of them instead.  The following:

```
L <- list(arg1, arg2, arg3)
do.call(f, L)
```

is same as:

```
f(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

but in the first case we can dynamically create L so that it could have any number of arguments whereas the second case is harded coded to three arguments.

**For example** this code which can be varied by varying n (where n can be 1, 2, 3, ...):

```
n <- 3
L <- lapply(1:n, function(i) i * BOD) # create list of n components

rowSums(do.call(cbind, L))
[1]  55.8  73.8 132.0 120.0 123.6 160.8
```

vs. this code which is hard coded to use 3 arguments to `cbind`:

```
rowSums(cbind(BOD, 2*BOD, 3*BOD)) # hard coded
[1]  55.8  73.8 132.0 120.0 123.6 160.8
```

Comment: Thanks!! That helped!!

Answer (score 3):

It creates a function called `psum` that accepts "anything" (...) and `na.rm` argument.
This is passed to `do.call` and everything that has been passed to `...` is being passed as a list. In essence, do.call will `cbind` anything that is passed in `...` with all the restrictions that are valid for `cbind`. If some value happens to be `NA`, it will be removed. Or not, depending on the `na.rm` value.